# Use custom proxy(ip, port, login and pass) in WebKit View

Tags: ios, webview, proxy, vpn, traffic

I am have app with WebKit View and when I open link inside them, I want use proxy by ip, port, login and pass, what I should do in this situation, I don't have any idea how solved this problem. Can anybody help understand algorithm and maybe show example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only for single request not for traffic interception, and I can load only html version of WebSite (

```
func loadAddressURL(url : String){
    
    
    let proxyHost : CFString = NSString(string: "****") as CFString
    let proxyPort : CFNumber = NSNumber(value: ****) as CFNumber
    let proxyEnable : CFNumber = NSNumber(value: 1) as CFNumber
    let proxyHostName : CFString = NSString(string: "****") as CFString
    let proxyPassword : CFString = NSString(string: "****") as CFString
  
    let proxyDict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: proxyEnable,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost: proxyHost,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort: proxyPort,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost: proxyHost,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort: proxyPort,
        kCFProxyTypeKey: kCFProxyTypeHTTPS,
        kCFProxyUsernameKey: proxyHostName,
        kCFProxyPasswordKey: proxyPassword
    ]
  
    let configuration : URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
          
    configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict
 
    let session : URLSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let requestURl = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url:requestURl! as URL)

    
    let task1: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                let myHtmlString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                self.webView.loadHTMLString(myHtmlString! as String, baseURL: nil)
                
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        
        });

    task1.resume()
}
```

Traffic interception not possible in WKWebkit because, all "request" was be moved out from app work process.